# React real-time chart with react.context and socket.io

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect, react-context

I'm trying to build a website for displaying real-time charts in typescript with react for my learning. But I can not get values from a server properly before displaying the chart.

What I want to do is ...

1. Communication protocol is websocket using socket.io.
2. Using socket.io and storing data are inside React.Context(`useSocket.tsx`) so as to access the data from any react components easily.
3. Displaying the data is in `Home.tsx`.
4. The socket events are `initial_data` and `new_data`.
5. The `initial_data` event is received at the time the accessing the website at first.
6. The `new_data` event is received at regularly.
7. The time getting both events above, update values inside `Home.tsx` automatically.

I researched some articles on the web, for example, explaining a way that using `socket.io` inside a `useEffect()` function that returning `socket.disconnect()`.
So, the code I built is below.

`useSocket.tsx`

```
import {useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {io, Socket} from "socket.io-client";
import {chartDataType} from "../types/chartDataType";

type Context = {
    chartData: Array<chartDataType>;
}

const SocketContext = createContext<Context>({
    chartData: [],
});

const SocketsProvider = (props: any) => {

    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState();

    useEffect( () => {
        const socket: Socket = io("http://***.***.***.***");

        socket.on('initial_data', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            setChartData(data);
        });

        socket.on('new_data', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });

        return () => { socket.disconnect() };
    },[]);

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={{chartData}} {...props} />
    );
}

const useSocket = () => useContext(SocketContext);

export { SocketsProvider, useSocket };
```

`Home.tsx`

```
import {memo, VFC} from "react";
import { useSocket } from "../../context/useSocket";
import {Heading} from "@chakra-ui/react";

export const Home: VFC = memo(() => {
    const { chartData } = useSocket();

    return (
        <>
            <Heading as="h1">{`${chartData}`}</Heading>
        </>
    )
})
```

The above code caused an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` occurred in the browser console. But when the comment out the `<Heading>...</Heading>` line in `Home.tsx`, the `console.log` in `useSocket.tsx` can display the value from the server in the browser console.

I can not come up with the idea for the correct implementation. Is the definition of the type of the `chartData` wrong? or other reasons? The definition of the `chartDataType` has nothing wrong.
What is the way for the correct implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is you are trying to render an empty array, the data hasn't loaded yet.

You need to check if charData exists, or if it's undefined first.

Like this:

```js
return ( 
   {CharData ? <Heading /> ... : null }
)
```